# issue in understanding the time parameter

Tags: javascript

I am having issue in understanding the `time` variable in the function `runAnimation`.
What will be its initial value and where its value comes from?

i am running the 'runAnimation' function in console but cant figure out how its initialized its first value.

```
function runAnimation(frameFunc) {
 let lastTime = null;
 function frame(time) {
  console.log(`time in frame function is : ${time}`);
  if (lastTime != null) {
    let timeStep = Math.min(time - lastTime, 100) / 1000;
     if (frameFunc(timeStep) === false) return;
   }
   lastTime = time;
   requestAnimationFrame(frame);
 }
 requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}

function runLevel(level, Display) {
 let display = new Display(document.body, level);
 let state = State.start(level);
 let ending = 1;
  return new Promise(resolve => {
  runAnimation(time => {  // i am confused with this variable
    state = state.update(time, arrowKeys);
    display.syncState(state);
    if (state.status == "playing") {
      return true;
     } else if (ending > 0) {
        ending -= time;
       return true;
     }  else {
       display.clear();
        resolve(state.status);
       return false;
     }
    }); 
 }); 
}
```

help me to understand the working of this function.

Answer (score 2):

It comes from the function [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#Syntax) which takes a function as a callback and is implicitly passed a time stamp.  In your example, the function `frame` is defined and passed as that callback.

> **callback**
>
> The function to call when it's time to update your animation for the next repaint. The callback function is passed one single argument, a DOMHighResTimeStamp similar to the one returned from performance.now(), indicating the point in time when requestAnimationFrame() starts to execute callback functions.

**[EDIT]**
I've tried to highlight/trace `time` or where a time value is passed

```
function runAnimation(frameFunc) { // (2) frameFunc is the callback
 let lastTime = null;
 function frame(time) { // (3) defining a callback for requestAnimationFrame
  console.log(`time in frame function is : ${time}`);
  if (lastTime != null) {
    let timeStep = Math.min(time - lastTime, 100) / 1000; // (5) time used here
     if (frameFunc(timeStep) === false) return; // (6) // value based on time passed here
   }
   lastTime = time;
   requestAnimationFrame(frame);
 }
 requestAnimationFrame(frame); // (4) this passes `time` as a param to it's callback `frame`
}

function runLevel(level, Display) {
 let display = new Display(document.body, level);
 let state = State.start(level);
 let ending = 1;
  return new Promise(resolve => {
  runAnimation(time => {  // (1) It is just the name of a parameter in the inline callback
    state = state.update(time, arrowKeys); // (7) now time is defined when this callback is finally called
    display.syncState(state);
    if (state.status == "playing") {
      return true;
     } else if (ending > 0) {
        ending -= time;
       return true;
     }  else {
       display.clear();
        resolve(state.status);
       return false;
     }
    }); 
 }); 
}
```

Comment: Note that MDN article was a bit wrong in this very part, the timestamp returned is not the one from `performance.now()`, it is just a similar one. This is even more true now that browsers did reduce the precision from timer functions against spectre and meltdown attacks (while rAF cb param still has the full precision). I did edit the MDN article to fix this small imprecision.

Comment: what is the value passed to `time` in line 4. and from where the value comes

Comment: It's passed from `requestAnimationFrame`.  When it is called, you pass it a callback, some time later it calls your callback and passes it a time value.